# Calling methods/variable scope

Tags: java

Just learned about calling methods and thought i'd try it out but my code does not function properly. It is supposed to take 2 names and print. That's all. My variables are global so all my methods should be able to see them, but when the program is run it prints 'null'. Can someone please explain why this isn't working? Is this something to do with passing the variable? I thought if it was global I wouldn't need to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserID {

String firstName;
String secondName;

public void readNames(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    firstName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter second name: ");
    secondName = scan.nextLine();

    scan.close();
}



public void printID(){

    System.out.println("Your user ID is: " + firstName);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserID readNames = new UserID();

    UserID printID = new UserID();


    readNames.readNames();

    printID.printID();


}
```

}

Comment: Why are you creating two objects of the same class? Once you figure out that question you should be able to figure it out

Comment: There is no such thing as a global variable in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are calling the read method from one instance of your 'UserID' class, and then trying to retrieve the name from another. Each instance you make, which is each time you do new, you are creating a new set of data. This may become more clear if you were to swap 'printID.printID();' to 'readNames.printID();'

As for a fix, you should try creating only one instance, then calling both methods on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating two objects of the class UserID. 
In readName object, you are changing the firstName and secondName variables but in printID object they are still null. This is because non static variables are associated with objects not class. So when you print the variables in printID object it prints null. As in the previous answer you can swap printID with readName.

```
readNames.printID();
```

Or you can make variables associated with class instead of object by making them static. Then for all the objects you create firtName and secondName will be common.

```
static String firstName;
static String secondName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below

```
   readNames.readNames();
   readNames.printID();

   printID.readNames();
   printID.printID();
```

Below variables are `instance variables` and they exists in the scope of object you create it.

```
String firstName;
String secondName;
```

In your code, you initialized the variables on `readNames` object. So to print the values of those variables, you have to call `printID()` method on that instance. Instead of calling   `printID()` method on `readNames` instance, you have invoked the method on `printID` object instance. But `printID` instance did not set the variables and you got Null as default value of that instance.

You will get right output if you use the same object by which you `readNames()` & `printID()`.

And one more thing : Have good naming conventions and do not use same name for objects and methods.